# Standard library sort and user defined types

Tags: c++

If I want to sort a vector of a UDT by one of two types of variables it holds, is it possible for the standard library sort to do this or do I need to write my own sort function.

For example if you had

```
struct MyType{
 int a;
 int b;
};

vector<MyType> moo;

// do stuff that pushes data back into moo

sort(moo.begin(), moo.end()) // but sort it by lowest to highest for a, not b
```

So is this possible using the stdlib sort? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is possible to use standard function if your type implements `"bool operator < (...) const"` and a copy constructor (compiler-generated or custom).

```
struct MyType {
    int a;
    int b;
    bool operator < (const MyType& other) const {
        ... // a meaningful implementation for your type
    }
    // Copy constructor (unless it's a POD type).
    MyType(const MyType &other)
        : a(other.a), b(other.b) { }
    // Some other form of construction apart from copy constructor.
    MyType()
        : a(0), b(0) { }
};
```

Alternatively, you can pass an ordering function (or a functor) as a third argument to `sort()` instead of implementing operator `"<"`.

```
bool type_is_less(const MyType& t1, const MyType& t2) { ... }
...
std::sort(c.begin(), c.end(), type_is_less);
```

This is useful in the following situations:

1. you don't want to implement operator `"<"` for whatever reason,
2. you need to sort a container of built-in or pointer types for which you can't overload operators.
3. you wish to sort the sequence using *different* orderings. ex: sometimes you want a struct with first/last name members sorted by first name, other times by last name. two different functions (or functors) make such options trivial.

Comment: Another option is to specialize `std::less` for your type. This way you don't have to pass the functor every time (e.g. because there really is one reasonable definition), and yet your type doesn't get `operator<`.

Comment: type_is_less can also be a "function object" (an object that overloads the () operator)

Comment: This has a serious flaw in that `operator<` isn't `const`. That means it won't work for code that considers the left-hand side of the comparison constant. (BTW, I've seen this wrong so often, this alone is enough of a reason to switch to making these operators global. Much less people get them wrong that way. Of course, there's other reasons, too.)

Comment: @sbi: typo. operator < should be const as designated in the paragraph above.

Comment: @Checkers: OK, I removed my down vote. :) Still, I strongly prefer to implement all binary operators treating both of their operands the same (i.e., not changing them) as free functions. With member functions, the left-hand operand might be treated different. With operators like comparison, you never want that.

Answer (score 4):

There's three ways to do this:

You could overload `operator<` for your class:

```
bool operator<(const MyType& lhs, const MyType& rhs) {return lhs.a<rhs.a;}
```

This has the disadvantage that, if you ever want to sort them according to `b`, you're out of luck.

You could also specialize `std::less` for your type. That makes `std::sort` working (and other things, like using the type as a key in a map) without hijacking `operator<` for this meaning. It does, however, still hijack a general-purpose comparison syntax for `a`, while you might, at other places in your code, compare your type according to `b`.

Or you could write your own comparator like this:

```
struct compare_by_a {
  bool operator()(const MyType& lhs, const MyType& rhs) const
  {return lhs.a<rhs.a;}
};
```

(Note: The `const` after the operator isn't strictly necessary. I still consider it good style, though.) This leaves the general-purpose means of comparison undefined; so if some code wants to use them without you being aware, the compile emits an error and makes you aware of it. You can use this or other comparators selectively and explicitly where ever you need comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, with C++ 20, you can use:

- universal initializers
- designated initializers
- sort function from ranges library
- projections
- structured bindings

Then, life will be simpler.

Please see:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
namespace rng = std::ranges;

// Some demo type
struct MyType {
    int a{};
    int b{};
};

int main () {

    // Test data
    std::vector<MyType> data{ {.b = 5}, {.b = 4}, {.b = 3}, {.b = 2},  {.b = 1} };

    // Sort it for b
    rng::sort(data, {}, &MyType::b);

    // Debug output
    for (const auto& [a, b] : data) std::cout << a << '\t' << b << '\n';
}
```