# Comparison of custom objects and operator overloading in C++

Tags: c++

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380463/sorting-a-vector-of-custom-objects) question about how to compare custom objects in C++.
I did not understand the operator overloading used here. What is the operator being overloaded here? Is it ()? What is the use of overloading that?

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int key;
    std::string stringValue;

    MyStruct(int k, const std::string& s) : key(k), stringValue(s) {}
};

struct less_than_key
{
    inline bool operator() (const MyStruct& struct1, const MyStruct& struct2)
    {
        return (struct1.key < struct2.key);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is to use a `less_than_key` object as a function:

```
less_than_key f;
bool result = f(key1, key2);
```

Object that can be called like functions (including garden variety functions) are sometimes called *functors* (warning: this is not the meaning of functor in mathematics), or *function objects*, or sometimes *functoids*.

Many standard library algorithms and containers expect such function objects as arguments. For instance, `std::map` can be customized with a binary function object (exactly like the one you showed us) to know how it should sort the keys.

Please refer to [this beginners' book list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and read about standard algorithms and containers to understand where you can use those beasts.

Function objects and iterators are the core of the C++ standard library, you should really learn about them to make the best use of C++.

Comment: +1 with one caveat: in this case I would point the OP to [this Booklist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) (esp. The beginners Books 2 & 4) rather than a reference page.

Answer (score 1):

The operator() is a function call operator with, probably, the most common use being to allow you to use normal function call syntax on an object that could be considered as behaving in a 'function-like' way.

In this example, you can call less_than_key() which is used by the STL sort.

Answer (score 1):

This is called functor. This is used heavily in C++ apis. Some of these apis take a functor which performs object specific operations.

```
Example pseudo code:

- Sorting a list of MyStruct objects.

sort api in algorithm.
std::list<MyStruct> mystructlist;
// populate mystructlist
sort(mystructlist.begin(), mystructlist.end(), less_than_key);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is often called the "functor" operator and it is useful because it mimics the syntax of a call to a regular function.

Objects with such an overloaded operator are often used with `stl`algorithms like `std::find_if()` or in your case, `std::sort()`.

Here are some samples:

```
std::vector<MyStruct> myvector;

less_than_key comparator;
std::sort(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), comparator);
```

Or:

```
MyStruct a, b;
less_than_key comparator;

if (comparator(a, b))
  // Do something
else
  // Do something else.
```

As you can see, there is not syntax difference between calling the `operator()` method of an instance of `less_than_key` and calling a function with the same prototype (well, disregarding of the hidden `this` parameter).