# Sorting a vector of objects in C++

Tags: c++

```
struct Keyword
{
    std::string keyword;
    int numUses;
};  

bool sortingVector(const Keyword& key1, const Keyword& key2)
{
    return key1.numUses < key2.numUses;
}

sort(topKeywords.begin(), topKeywords.end(), sortingVector);



: no matching function for call to 'sort(std::vector<Keyword>::iterator, std::vector<Keyword>::iterator, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'
        c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:5236:18: note: candidate is: void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Keyword*, std::vector<Keyword> >, _Compare = bool (NewsAggregatorImpl::*)(const Keyword&, const Keyword&)]
```

Why isn't this correct, my compiler gives me that error.
And i want my function to be global.
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is `sortingVector` a non-static member of some class?  The error message suggests that it is, in which case you will need to wrap it (using `boost::bind`, for example) into a binary operation that doesn't take a `this` parameter.  You might want to make `sortingVector` a static member or a free function instead.

Comment: yes, that was the problem, i didint know that. I'll keep that in mind next time, thank you

Answer (score 4):

This is what a compilable example should look like:

Because you did not provide the exact code that was generating the errors people have given a couple of different types of answer. As a result it is generally a good idea to generate a compilable example the displays the problem.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct Keyword
{
        std::string keyword;
            int numUses;
};

bool sortingVector(const Keyword& key1, const Keyword& key2)
{
        return key1.numUses < key2.numUses;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Keyword>    topKeywords;

    std::sort(topKeywords.begin(), topKeywords.end(), sortingVector);
}
```

Generally the compiler can do a better job of optimising (I am told) if you use a functor rather than a function pointer.

```
struct SortingVectorFunctor
{
    bool operator()(const Keyword& key1, const Keyword& key2) const
    {
        return key1.numUses < key2.numUses;
    }
};
```

Comment: ... because it will instantiate `std::sort` with a template argument specific to your functor type, whose `operator()` therefore can easily be inlined into that instantiation. With a function pointer, the instantiation of `std::sort` is only for the function pointer type, not for the exact function, so inlining a call to the particular function actually pointed to by the pointer is a harder job. It can't be inlined into the instantiation, only into an inlined replacement of the call to the instantiation. At least, that's what I'm told ;-)

Comment: But if the function is fixed at compile time then I see no reason that the function can not be inlined. The trouble for a compiler is proving that a function pointer is not modified at runtime, so even though we know it is not changed can the compiler prove it.

Comment: You see no reason why the comparator cannot be inlined into (say) `std::sort<Keyword*, Keyword*, bool(*)(const Keyword&, const Keyword&>`, or you see no reason why `std::sort<that lot>` can't be inlined into `main`? In any case, what's relevant isn't whether it *can* be inlined (of course it can, provided that `std::sort` is inlined), it's whether it actually will be inlined, and there are more potential obstacles to inlining in the case of the function pointer. That's all, I don't think anyone is claiming that the function pointer case is *guaranteed* to be slower than the functor.

Comment: As for "can it prove it", that particular part is basically the same problem the compiler faces when it inlines a function and you've passed it (say) an integer literal as a parameter. Decent optimizers do propagate the value through the inlined code, and can for example do dead code elimination for conditionals involving the previously-variable-parameter-now-constant-value. So it's certainly not beyond the wit of a normal compiler to determine what function is actually called, provided `std::sort` is inlined.

Answer (score 1):

I believe right example here -> [Sorting a vector of custom objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380463/sorting-a-vector-of-custom-objects)

Comment: Yes, but using a function for comparison is fine too.

Answer (score 1):

Put `std::` in front of your `sort` call.  And `#include <algorithm>` at the top of the source file.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to call `std::sort` instead of plain sort and might have to include the appropriate header file (`algorithm`unless I'm mistaken).

Comment: yes, Ive included, looks like i had to make that function static

Answer (score 0):

are you `using namespace std;` ? if not you want `std::sort()`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

struct Keyword
{
    std::string keyword;
    int numUses;
};  

bool sortingVector(const Keyword& key1, const Keyword& key2)
{
    return key1.numUses < key2.numUses;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Keyword> topKeywords(100);

    // imagine topKeywords initialization here

    std::sort(topKeywords.begin(), topKeywords.end(), sortingVector);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiles fine on my machine (gcc version 4.4.3).

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple sortingVector functions - thus the `<unresolved overloaded function type>` part of your error.