# sorting vectors of custom objects

Tags: c++, sorting, object, vector

```
class hash
{
private:

    static const int tableSize = 1000;
    struct item
    {
        string name;
        unsigned int reps;
        item* next;
    };
    item* HashTable[tableSize];
}
```

In my program I constructed my hashtable with this structure, and I am using chaining. These items holds very similar strings, and an integer variable with them, storing how many times they occur in a text file.
I want to write a function to print most frequent K strings in the context.

```
void PrintTopFrequentList(int K);
```

My resulting hash table is actually very big,maybe 100.000 entries?
What I have got so far is this...

```
void hash::PrintTopFrequentList(int length)
{
    vector<item*> row;
    vector<item*> sorted;
    int no;
    for ( int i = 0 ; i<tableSize ; i++)
    {
        item* Ptr= HashTable[i];

        while ( Ptr->next!=NULL )
        {
            row.push_back(Ptr);
            Ptr=Ptr->next;
        }
        sort(row.begin(),row.end());
        sorted.insert(sorted.end(), row.begin(),row.end());
        sort(sorted.begin(),sorted.end());
    }
```

My problems are, first of all those `sort` functions at the end of `PrintTopFreq`. Function does not seem to work, after the for loop I add this part to control sorting, but it didn't work.

What I actually need to do is to customize this sort function such that my result vector will be in Descending order. I tried some function overloading inside class definition I looked from other posts but couldn't make it work.
I tried reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265291/sorting-a-vector-of-objects-in-c) but it didn't help.

Comment: uhm, maybe you could simply sort on reverse iterators? `sort(row.rbegin(), row.rend())` ?

Comment: only question I can spot is "...100.000 entries?" how are we supposed to know? :P Please describe what brings you to the conclusion that it doesnt work, because "doesnt work" can mean anything

Comment: sort(row.rbegin(), row.rend()) did reversing the list Im printing to control, but still I do not have a sorted list it went from 11114111211111 to 111112111411111 for example

Comment: @methodp Put additional information into your question please, as comment it's not useful.

Comment: *My resulting hash table is actually very big,maybe 100.000 entries* -- Honestly, that's not "very big".

Answer (score 0):

To sort something the sort algorithm needs to know how to compare items [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). Otherwise it will use the default comparison for int. Either you implement comparison operators (<, >, ==) for item (or implement a comparison class for your item).