# Sort vector of vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, c++14

I have a vector of vectors of int like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec_vec{{3,5,1,6},{2,4},...};
```

The results should be

```
 Case1:   {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6}} 
 Case2:  {1,2,3,4,5,6}
 Case3:  {{1, 3, 5, 6}, {2, 4}}
```

I found many ways to do this, the best one I found need complexity `O(n^2)` to sort them.

What's the best complexity for the `case1`, `case2` and `case3`?

So what's the best way to write a native (c++11,c++14) cross platform code to sort that's vector? is `O(n^2)` is the best complexity? The memory is important also.

I checked this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14419520/sort-vector-of-vectors), but it seems it also took `O(n^2)` to sort the vectors?

Comment: Do you suppose that result should be `{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6}}`?

Comment: If I understand, you want to **merge** your vectors first and then to sort the merged one, right? Merge without repetitions?

Comment: @PaoloM : or sort each vector first, then merge

Comment: Could you do by insertion? loop over the vector and insert in new vector in their order...

Comment: What is `n`? Is it the number of vectors or the total number of values in all the vectors?

Comment: What's your O(n^2) solution? The builtin sort function is O(nlogn) in the average case. For the third case you don't even need to do anything except sort.

Comment: In case 2 first you merge them and then you sort them. In case 3 you sort them individually, without sorting. But in case 1? Do you merge them, sort, and then split them again based on the number of elements in the original vectors?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest case is case 2. To solve that, make a temporary new vector, move all elements there, and sort the new vector.

```
std::vector<int> temp;
for (const auto& vec: vec_vec)
{
    std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::back_inserter(temp));
}
std::sort(temp.begin(), temp.end());
```

The copying part is O(n); the sorting part is O(n log(n)).

To implement case 1, copy the elements from `temp` back to `vec_vec` - this should be easy.