# Sort a vector of a structure object according an element of the structure - c++

Tags: c++, sorting, structure

So, I'm trying to sort a `vector` of a custom object `myStruct` according to `num1` in the structure.
I have to following code:

```
struct myStruct{

    int num1;
    std::vector<int> vecStruct;
    int num2;

    myStruct(int n1, std::vector<int> j, int n2) : num1(n1), vecStruct(j), num2(n2) {}

    bool operator < (const myStruct& s) const
    {
        return (num1 < s.num1);
    }
};
```

and then I use this to sort:

```
sort(myVector.begin(), myVector.end());
```

where

```
std::vector<myStruct> myVector;
```

I've tried to follow [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380463/sorting-a-vector-of-custom-objects) instructions, but I keep getting a a compiling error:

> No matching constructor for initialisation of 'myStruct'

I'm using Xcode 4.6.2 on MacOSX Mountain Lion - not that it matters, but Xcode is what's giving me this error

Comment: You're missing a constructor for myStruct.

Answer (score 3):

In the code you've presented above, your constructor name doesn't match the name of the struct (myStruct vs student).  I'd start by fixing that.

Answer (score 2):

When I tested your code, but changing the name of your struct to `student` (given that is what it's referred to inside the struct), I received no compilation errors.

Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: I changed that, I still get the same compiling error... I don't understand how it works on yours but not on mine

Comment: May I ask, how are you compiling it? I try to build it with Xcode and it doesn't work. Neither does it with `g++`

Comment: VS Express 2012.  Unfortunately I don't have Xcode to test it with, but I don't see anything in the code that looks controversial to not be cross-compilable.  When you corrected the syntax did the error just change to `"No matching constructor for initialisation of 'student'"`?

Comment: Ignore the bit about `student` above, I just noticed you'd changed it all to `myStruct`.   Can you include the code you're using to populate the vector? I was getting a similar error when playing around because I briefly used the (non-existent) default constructor to populate the vector.