# What is a standard way of sorting a std::vector of type <std::pair<int, std::pair<int, int>>> based on the "first" of the first pair

Tags: c++, stl

Teh carried by the vector is a pair indexed by an id:

`<std::pair<int, std::pair<int, int>>>`

```
         496              1,   256

        (message id)
```

As you can see, the "id" is repetitive. For further processing of this data, it will be logically very useful for me to sort that triplet on the basis of "message id". How can I do this using STL functions ?

Here is some data sample:

```
 15:38:08.307 - (I) ET02 -  For message Id: 496 Tag - value pair: 1 - 256
 15:38:08.307 - (I) ET02 -  For message Id: 496 Tag - value pair: 2 - 27060
 15:38:08.307 - (I) ET02 -  For message Id: 496 Tag - value pair: 3 - 2014-06-16T17:07:00.519
 15:38:08.307 - (I) ET02 -  For message Id: 487 Tag - value pair: 1 - 1044
 15:38:08.307 - (I) ET02 -  For message Id: 487 Tag - value pair: 2 - 9098150000
 15:38:08.307 - (I) ET02 -  For message Id: 498 Tag - value pair: 1 - 9098150000
 15:38:08.307 - (I) ET02 -  For message Id: 498 Tag - value pair: 2 - 9098150000
 15:38:08.307 - (I) ET02 -  For message Id: 498 Tag - value pair: 3 - 5902400000000
 15:38:08.307 - (I) ET02 -  For message Id: 498 Tag - value pair: 501 - 256000000000
 15:38:08.307 - (I) ET02 -  For message Id: 498 Tag - value pair: 502 - 0
 15:38:08.307 - (I) ET02 -  For message Id: 498 Tag - value pair: 503 - 0
 15:38:08.307 - (I) ET02 -  For message Id: 498 Tag - value pair: 504 - 9098150000
 15:38:08.307 - (I) ET02 -  For message Id: 498 Tag - value pair: 505 - 9098150000
```

Comment: Depending on that "first pair" means, it could be as simpla as `std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());`.

Comment: Please put code in the question, not the title.

Comment: @juanchopanza I mean the message id. Which is the 'first' of the first pair.

Comment: Just try the `sort` I suggested then. But "first pair" isn't descriptive enough. I still have to guess what you mean.

Comment: "As you can see, the "id" is repetitive".. I can? *You can.* *I* see three numbers, some text, and no code. I *think* juan is correct, and it it isn't enough, a `std::tupple` and `std::tie`-based comparator may do what you need.

Comment: @WhozCraig really sorry brother. I meant to attach the sample in the first go, skipped it by mistake. I have attached it now.

Comment: @RitwikG no worries. is that chart the format you want. I.e. it looks like its sorted on the primary column you're interested in, then the secondary data, is that correct? If so, I think juan and Ali are exactly right. the default comparator for `std::pair<>` will work.

Comment: @WhozCraig yes, that is correct. I need it sorted by the first column. I do not know how I can use sort in the case of the vector carrying a templated type. This is my question.

Comment: Both juan and Ali pretty-much spelled it out. Take your vector, and just invoke `std::sort(v.begin(), v.end())`. I'm pretty confident it will do exactly what you need if the pairing is laid out like you described it in your snippet.

Comment: @RitwikG Have you tried the provided solution in my answer to see if it does what you want?

Comment: @AliAlamiri yes, it did. Thanks. Also, in case I wanted to add my own comparator (since I do not want to waste time and CPU cycles sorting the `second` of the pair), where must I start ?

Comment: depending on what you want to do you could store this data in a `std::multimap` (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap)

Comment: @RitwikG Just implement the comparator and pass it to the sort function as the third parameter. Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380463/sorting-a-vector-of-custom-objects

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you use `std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());`, it will sort by the first element, then by the second. So if you just use the default sort, you'll get the desired ordering.
This is because `std::pair` overloads the `<` operator to firstly sort by the `first` element and then by the `second`.

Comment: +1, and special note, "then by the second", if the "second" is also a pair, will do the exact same thing, which can be damn-handy.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks for the extra note :)