# C++ Sorting a struct vector alphabetically

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I've got a task that I'm stuck on. I need to create a program that reads an input file, stores each word into a vector along with how many times that word was read (hence the struct). Those values then need to print out in alphabetical order.

I've come up with something that I think is along the right lines:

```
struct WordInfo {
string text;
int count; 
} uwords, temp;

string word;
int count = 0; //ignore this. For a different part of the task
vector<WordInfo> uwords;

while (cin >> word) {
    bool flag = false;
    count += 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < uwords.size(); i++) {
        if (uwords[i].text == word) {
            flag = true;
            uwords[i].count += 1;
        }
    }
    if (flag == false) {
        if (count == 1) { //stores first word into vector
            uwords.push_back(WordInfo());
            uwords[0].count = 1;
            uwords[0].text = word;
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < uwords.size(); i++) {
                if (word < uwords[i].text) {
                    uwords.push_back(WordInfo());
                    WordInfo temp = {word, 1};
                    uwords.insert(uwords.begin() + i, temp);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem I'm having, is that when I run the program it appears to get stuck in an infinite loop and I can't see why. Although I've done enough testing to realise it's probably in that last if statement, but my attempts to fix it were no good. Any help is appreciated. Cheers.

EDIT: I forgot to mention, we must use vector class and we're limited in what we can use, and sort is not an option :(

Comment: Take a look at the header `<algorithm>`, especially `std::sort`.

Comment: I guess you cannot use `std::sort`, right? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

Comment: One way: Use a map with words as keys and count their occurence as value.

Comment: Could the infinite loop be caused by `while(cin >> word)`? Normally, this means that the program is waiting for user input.

Comment: Check this discussion for an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380463/sorting-a-vector-of-custom-objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
            if (word < uwords[i].text) {
                uwords.push_back(WordInfo());
                WordInfo temp = {word, 1};
                uwords.insert(uwords.begin() + i, temp);
            }
```

Take a good look at this piece of code:

First, it will actually insert 2 words into your list; one time an "empty" one with `push_back`, and one time with `insert`. And it will do that whenever the current word is smaller than the one at the position `i`.

And as soon as it has inserted, there's 2 new elements to walk over; one actually being at the current position of `i`, so in the next iteration, we will again compare the same word - so your loop gets stuck because index `i` increases by 1 each iteration, but the increase of `i` only steps over the just inserted element!

For a quick solution, you want to (1) search for the position where the word before is "smaller" than the current one, but the next one is bigger. Something like

```
if (uwords[i-1].text < word && word < uwords[i].text) {
```

(2) and you want to get rid of the `push_back` call.

Furthermore, (3) you can break the loop after the if condition was true - you have already inserted then, no need to iterate further. And (4), with a bit of condition tweaking, the `count == 1` can actually be merged into the loop. Modified code part (will replace your whole `if (code == false)` block - warning, not tested yet):

```
if (!flag) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= uwords.size(); ++i) {
        if ((i == 0 || uwords[i-1].text < word) &&
            (i == uwords.size() || word < uwords[i].text)) {
            WordInfo temp = {word, 1};
            uwords.insert(uwords.begin() + i, temp);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I thought at first glance, but I don't think it's infinite because the `if` is not satisfied at every iteration.  It's very exponential, however.

Comment: @paddy it is, as soon as a word is encountered where word is smaller than any uwords entry. When inserting the new word, and then increasing i, it means that in subsequent loops we are actually comparing the same word over and over

Comment: Ahh true.  There's a sign that I should go to bed instead of browsing SO =)

Comment: I added push_back in there a bit out of desperation. Unfortunately, just having the insert function still yields the infinite loop.

Comment: did you read my whole answer and do it the way I write? or did you just remove the push_back?

Comment: Sorry, I only just saw the rest of the answer. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: The good news is that the infinite loop is gone. But now the program is only reading in the first word of the input, and nothing after that. I'll keep tinkering with it.

Comment: how do you figure that it reads nothing after that? what do you give as input, what is the output? maybe create a new question with it

Comment: @nyarlathotep I had to change a few minor pieces with your code, but nothing major (thanks for the foundation). The other problem which took me a while to figure out was that if the word was greater than the last word of the vector, it wouldn't add the word in because my code was only dealt with words less than. E.g. if the first word is 'in', then only words starting with letter a-h would be added to the vector. The solution was a simple if statement that executes if a word wasn't placed in the vector.

Comment: ah of course ;) - with a bit of condition tweaking, you actually shouldn't need any additional if blocks at all - see my updated answer (even the count == 1 if block should be superfluous)

Answer (score 2):

You should not push your words nin vector, but in map

```
std::map<std::string,int>
```

Since map has comparable keys iterator over map, automaticaly returns sorted range that can be later pushed in vector if needed.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately we're limited to using the vector class