# Sorting dates (string) stored in vector

Tags: c++

I have a vector that contains dates in this format, DDMMMYY, e.g `12Jan14`

```
vector<string> tempDate
```

When I use the STL sort, basically it will work when all of the dates are in the same year/month. `01Jan14`, `05Jan14`, `11Jan14`, etc. But when I enter `02Feb14`, it will all be messed up.

`sort (tempDate.begin(), tempDate.end())`

Can anyone tell me what went wrong with it?

Edit: I tried to use templates, but it doesn't work as all the string got 'split' up.
I did some troubleshooting inside the sortDayMonthYear

```
template <class T>
bool sortDayMonthYear(T a, T b)
{
   for (int i =0; i < a.size(); i++)
       cout << a.at(i)<< endl;
}
```

What i get is something like this

```
0
1
J
A
N
1
4
0
2
J
A
N
1
4
```

Actually what I intend to do is to pass the two strings into the template function, using substr to get the day, month, year, compare and return true or false.

Comment: The string is not 'split-up', you're just outputting `endl` after each character.

Comment: What does "it will all be messed up" mean?

Comment: Do you really need to store the strings in such an inconvenient format? The conventional "YYYYMMDD" is fairly readable to humans, and can simply be sorted lexicographically.

Comment: @MikeSeymour the convention is YYYYMMDD of course

Comment: @CashCow: Thanks, my fingers were faster than my brain.

Comment: One of the great and terrible things about C++ programs is that they do exactly what you tell them to do.  There's no magic involved.  `"Jan"` will never come before `"Aug"`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply people. The expected output when i cout << a.at(i)<< endl; should be 01Jan14. Not just 0. @NemanjaBoric

Comment: I'm sorry that was a mistake, I thought i'm passing the whole vector into the function. Silly mistake. Appreciate all the replies.

Answer (score 3):

Your predicate should take two constant string references as argument, and then use those to decide which one is "lesser" than the other.

So:

```
bool sortDayMonthYear(const std::string& first, const std::string& second)
{
    // Algorithm to find out which string is "lesser" than the other
}
```

Then you use that comparator function when sorting:

```
std::sort(std::begin(tempDate), std::end(tempDate), sortDayMonthYear);
```

Answer (score 2):

The standard way of sorting strings is lexicographical (by alphabet, for each letter, just like in a dictionary).

Therefore, what you need is your own comparator. There is a version of sort which takes one as third parameter. See e.g. this question for starting ideas: [Sorting a vector of custom objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380463/sorting-a-vector-of-custom-objects)