# Sorting an std::list that contains structs

Tags: c++, list, sorting, stl

So I'm having some trouble figuring out the proper use of `list::sort()` in regards to a list of structs. Heres the relevant code:

```
struct student
{
    char firstnm[20],   
        lastnm[20];     
    int id,             
        grade;
};
list<student> sList;

//Irrelevant code...

cout << "Please enter your own name, id, and grade. (Ex: myfirst mylast 0 12)\n";
cin >> data.firstnm >> data.lastnm >> data.id >> data.grade;
sList.push_back(data);
sList.sort();
```

The problem I'm trying to solve is using `sList.sort()` to sort by `id`. However, I have no idea how to properly pass it into `list::sort()`. Thanks in advance for any help/time!

EDIT: The solution was simply adding this to my struct

```
bool operator < (const student& cmp) const {
   return id < cmp.id;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give a look to std::sort. (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) There is multiple definitions of that function, and one where you can specify on what you want to sort.

Also, give a look to that post, I think it's what you need : https://stackoverflow.com/a/21234017/6663947

Edit :

thats an exemple of comparator :

```
sList.sort([](const student & a, const student & b) { return a.id < b.id; });
```

I did not tried it, but it should look like it. Also, this is for c++11

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you! I think you're right. I'll start playing around with it. So what you're saying though is I'll need to use the sort from #include <algorithm> after creating an overload for a lessthan operation, rather than the one supplied by the STL?

Comment: Yeah, so you need to add a comparator. You could also use the sList.sort() like you did, but with the comparator as parameter...

Comment: @kseaner You don't have to use the `sort` from the `<algorithm>` header or include it at all. You only have to pass your definition of `less` either as a function, a function object or a lambda. You could also define `operator<` for you `student`-type and don't pass anything to `sort`

Comment: @kseaner Note that you can't use `std::sort` from `<algorithm>` to sort a `std::list`. It requires random-access iterators and won't compile if you give it `std::list` iterators. That's why `std::list::sort` exists.

Answer (score 2):

The member function [`std::list::sort()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort) is overloaded. `std::list` has an ordinary member function that takes no parameters and uses `operator<` for sorting the elements of the list:

```
void sort();
```

It also has a member function template taking one parameter `comp` that is used as the predicate for sorting the elements:

```
template<class Compare> 
void sort(Compare comp);
```

---

Assuming you want to sort the `student` objects in your list according to the *key* `id` in *ascending order*. You can either define `operator<` for your user-defined `student` class as:

```
bool operator<(student const& a, student const& b) {
   return a.id < b.id;
}
```

and use the overload that takes no parameters:

```
sList.sort(); // 1st overload
```

or simply plass a lambda expression to the member function template taking one parameter:

```
auto cmp = [](auto const& a, auto const& b) {
   return a.id < b.id;
}; 

sList.sort(cmp); // 2nd overload
```

with this approach, you don't need to define `operator<` for your `student` class.

---

Note that you can't use the [`std::sort()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) algorithm on `std::list`'s iterators, because this algorithm requires *random-access* iterators, but an `std::list` only provides *bidirectional* iterators. Therefore, the following code won't compile:

```
std::sort(sList.begin(), sList.end());
```

Instead, you have to use the member functions provided by `std::list` in order to sort the elements of the container as explained above.