# Sorting a 2D vector of objects

Tags: c++, sorting

I am working on a little puzzle game ( Gem Puzzle).

I have a puzzle Piece object for each piece on the board that has the following attributes:

```
Position Pcorrect_;
Position Pactuel_;
bool estvide_;
```

(the 3rd attribute is irrelevant for this question)

The Position is simple structure consisting of:

```
unsigned ligne;
unsigned colonne;
```

Each Piece is stored in a vector of a vector.

```
std::vector<std::vector<Piece>> board_;
```

The Pieces eventually get mixed around so the correct attribute (location) does not match the actual attribute (location).

I am stuck on a method that should sort the board.The actual position has to match the current position for each piece of the board.

Is there an elegant way of doing this with a sort function ?My current approach is using 4 loops and lots of conditions which is probably the wrong way of doing it.

Comment: Have a look at the `std::sort` function.

Comment: Also if you use std::sort you might have to implement a comparison (<) operator inside your Piece class. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380463/sorting-a-vector-of-custom-objects

Comment: Use `std::sort`, and provide it with a function that takes `std::vector<Piece>` and returns a `bool`. You can then use `std::sort` again within that function to define how you want to compare them.

Answer (score 0):

if you use C++11, you can create a tuple  and sort it.

You can define a custom comparison, like in this example:

http://www.hongliangjie.com/2011/10/10/sortin-tuples-in-c/