# QTCreator function placement - error: reference to non-static member function must be called-

Tags: widget, qt-creator

I am new on the QT world. And I am confused to where to put my small bool function:

```
    bool Widget::compareBy(const dist_obj &a, const dist_obj &b)
{
    return a.distance < b.distance;
}
```

and I want to call it from `void Widget::update_window()

like:
`

```
std::sort(found_obj.begin() , found_obj.end() , compareBy);
```

it gave:

```
error: reference to non-static member function must be called
```

I am using this function in my normal c++11 Clion environment. What am I doing wroin in this QT world :O

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer which is worked for me from [sorting a vector of classes based on a variable in the class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29676147/sorting-a-vector-of-classes-based-on-a-variable-in-the-class)

worked like a charm without defining any function or class.