# c++ How to sort a vector of bitsets?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, bitset

I have a vector of `bitsets`:

```
vector < bitset<1024> > myvector;
```

What is the best way to sort this vector from:

> 0: xxx0100 
> 1: xxx1100
> 2: xxx0010
> 3: xxx0001
> ...
> ...

to this order:

> 0: xxx0001
> 1: xxx0010
> 2: xxx0100
> 3: xxx1100
> ...
> ...

I already tried to do this with std:sort, but it didn't work, because std:sort use the "<" - operator, which doesn't work for bitsets.

Thanks in advance for your help! Any suggestions or ideas are greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**
My question is different to [Sorting a vector of custom objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380463/sorting-a-vector-of-custom-objects), because it is impossible to use "<"- operator for `bitset`. So my question is, which operator can I use instead, to compare `bitset`?

Comment: You can use std::sort with a custom comparator.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Could you explain me, how to do this? Or give an example?

Comment: Try to do a websearch. Also, make sure you read the documentation concerning the sorting function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A simple way to sort a `std::bitset` would be to convert it to a `std::string` using [`std::bitset::to_string`](http://std::bitset::to_string) and then use `std::string`s `operator<` to compare the bitsets.

```
std::vector<std::bitset<128>> data = {1000,2000,80000,15,6000,2};
std::sort(data.begin(), data.end(), [](const auto & lhs, const auto & rhs)
                                    { return lhs.to_string() < rhs.to_string(); });
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6df951f3ccf8c4c)</kbd>

As pointed out in the comments if the bitset is small enough to fit into a `unsigned long long` then you can use [`std::bitset::to_ullong`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/to_ullong) and compare the `unsigned long long`s instead of strings.

Comment: @MooingDuck Totally agree but the OP wants to compare bitsets of 1024 bits which cannot be represented as a `unsigned long long`

Comment: Totally overlooked that.  That makes the `to_ulong` code much more complicated.  Alright.