# Sorting a Vector of Custom Objects by overloading <

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, overloading

I am trying to sort a vector of nodes. 
I followed the advice from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380463/sorting-a-vector-of-custom-objects) and overloaded my 
 ***struct's < operator***. However I am not getting a sorted list after sort is called.

```
struct node
{

    int frequency ;
    char data;

    bool operator < (const node& n1) const
    {
        return (frequency < n1.frequency);
    }
};
```

I call sort by the following:

```
vector<node*> test
//fill test with nodes
sort(test.begin(),test.end());
```

Output:

```
Presort data is: 1,1,2,3,3,1,2,1,1
Postsort data is: 3,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,3
```

Comment: What do `left` and `right` refer to?  They may need to be updated after the sort.

Comment: That was for other parts of the code not listed here. I removed them to reduce confusion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are sorting a vector of pointers, but the operator applies to a `struct`, C++ ignores your operator `<` overload.

You can supply a custom comparer that calls your `operator <`, like this

```
std::sort(test.begin(), test.end(), [](const node* pa, const node* pb) {
    return (*pb) < (*pa);
});
```

or code the comparison straight into the lambda, and drop the unused overload of `<`, like this:

```
std::sort(test.begin(), test.end(), [](const node* pa, const node* pb) {
    return pb->frequency < pa->frequency;
});
```

Comment: Your first solution uses a pair of parenthesis for each pointer which is totally useless. Dereferencing a pointer does not require parenthesis.

Comment: I am attempting to get your solution to work, but as of yet, no luck

Comment: @Matt This requires C++11 or higher. VC does not have it; g++ use `-std=c++11` option.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I am using g++ with the -std=c++11 option

Comment: This works, it was user error on my part as to why it wasn't working for me. It's been a long night, thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is to use lambdas:

```
sort(test.begin(),test.end(), [](const node &lhs, const node &rhs){return lhs->frequency < rhs->frequency;});
```

Comment: You need to change &lhs and &rhs  to *lhs and *rhs. By doing those changes, I was able to get this to work immediately