# How to sort arrays by variable (int - least to greatest) in arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, c++11, int

I have 10 arrays like this:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

struct person
{
    int age, i;
    char name[20], dob[20], pob[20], gender[7];
};

int main ()
{
    int i = 0;
    person person[10];
    for (i; i<10; i++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter your name, date of birth, place of birth, gender, and age, separated by a space.\nFor example, John 1/15/1994 Maine Male 20: ";
        scanf("%s %s %s %s %d", &person[i].name, &person[i].dob, &person[i].pob, &person[i].gender, &person[i].age);
        printf("%s %s %s %s %d \n", &person[i].name, &person[i].dob, &person[i].pob, &person[i].gender, person[i].age);
    }
    sort(person)
    return 0;
}
```

How can I sort all of these arrays by age? Age is an int, least to greatest? Thanks.

Comment: You should use a std::vector

Comment: @Mikhail Why is that?

Comment: @johnny880 they are efficient in terms of space and time as compared to arrays.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting a vector of custom objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380463/sorting-a-vector-of-custom-objects)

Comment: @NickyC Well he didn't use a vector so its probably not a duplicate. Although he should have used a vector...

Answer (score 0):

create a lambda as

```
auto func = [](Person p1, Person p2)
{
   return p1.age1 < p2.age2;
}
```

use `std::sort` to sort the items

```
std::sort(person.begin(),person.end(),func);
```

hope it helps

Working code will look like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>

struct Person{
    std::string name_, dob_, pob_;
    char gender_;
    int age_;

    Person(std::string name,std::string dob, std::string pob,char gender,int age)
    :name_(name),dob_(dob),pob_(pob),gender_(gender),age_(age)
    {
    }

    void print() const
    {
        std::cout<<name_<<" , "<<dob_<<" , "<<pob_<<" , "<<gender_<<" , "<<age_<<'\n'; 
    }
};

int main()
{


    std::array<Person,10> arr{
        Person{"AA","12/12/12","BB",'M',24},
        Person{"AA","12/12/12","BB",'M',23},
        Person{"AA","12/12/12","BB",'M',22},
        Person{"AA","12/12/12","BB",'M',21},
        Person{"AA","12/12/12","BB",'M',20},
        Person{"AA","12/12/12","BB",'M',34},
        Person{"AA","12/12/12","BB",'M',33},
        Person{"AA","12/12/12","BB",'M',32},
        Person{"AA","12/12/12","BB",'M',31},
        Person{"AA","12/12/12","BB",'M',30}
    };
    auto func = [] (Person p1,Person p2)
    {
        return p1.age_ < p2.age_;
    };
    std::sort(arr.begin(),arr.end(),func);

    for(auto const & item:arr)
    {
        item.print();
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't get it? Sorry, can you implement it into the code? Thanks.

Comment: Edited OP. Maybe i didn't explain clearly. please look at it again

Comment: You first read about basic input/output in C, see `scanf` and `printf` line in your code. once you'll read the data correctly any of the solution suggested here will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `std::sort(begin, end, comparator)` function that comes with `#include<algorithm>` and provide your custom comparator which in this case would be

```
bool comparator(Person i, Person j) {
     return i.age < j.age;
}

std::sort(&Person[0], &Person[len], comparator);
//better alternative
std::sort(std::begin(Person), std::end(Person), comparator);
```

Comment: i don't get it? Sorry, can you implement it into the code? Thanks.

Comment: The sort function provides you the functionality of sorting. You just have to pass the start and end of the arrays to it. Since your data is a custom one, it has no way to know how to sort it. You might get abrupt results. That's why the 3rd parameter is a function pointer. The sort function calls this each time it tries comparing two Person objects. This function should return false if the first element is small than second or true otherwise. @johnny880

Comment: Edited OP. Maybe i didn't explain clearly. please look at it again

Comment: @FaizHalde: If `len` is the number of elements, your first example should be `std::sort(&Person[0], &Person[len], comparator);`. The second parameter needs to be a _one-past-the-end_ iterator.