# How can I sort a vector of unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, vector, unique-ptr

I declared a vector as follows: `vector<unique_ptr<Worker>> Workers`. `Worker` is a base class with a private field `name` and it has two derived classes: `Builder` and `Driver`.

I add to the `Workers` vector objects of `Builder` and `Driver` and then I want to sort the vector by `name` using `#include <algorithm>` like this:

```
sort(Workers.begin(), Workers.end(), cmp_by_name);

bool cmp_by_name(const Worker &a, const Worker &b)
{
    return a.getName() < b.getName();
}
```

But the VS compiler says:

> Error 1   error C2664: 'bool (const Worker &,const Worker &)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'std::unique_ptr>' to 'const Worker &' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\algorithm    3071    1   App

How can I fix this error?

---

Thanks to @NathanOliver, @Rabbid76 and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380463/sorting-a-vector-of-custom-objects), I edited my `cmp_by_name` into this form:

```
struct cmp_by_name
{
    inline bool operator()(const unique_ptr<Worker>& a, const unique_ptr<Worker>& b)
    {
        return a->getName() < b->getName();
    }
};
```

And I call the sort function like this:

```
sort(Workers.begin(), Workers.end(), cmp_by_name());
```

Comment: Signature of the predicate is wrong.

Comment: You should move the part with your solution into a new answer. This way, your post would better fit Stack Overflow's Q&A format and people could provide upvotes for you solution.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The comparison function which [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) uses needs to be in the form of:

```
bool cmp(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);
```

Here the types `Type1` and `Type2` must be such that the iterator can be dereferenced and then implicitly converted to both of them.

In your case dereferencing `Workers.begin()` gives you a `unique_ptr<Worker>` not a `Worker`. You will need to change your comparison function to take a `const unique_ptr<Worker>&`.

In this case it would wind up looking like:

```
bool cmp_by_name(const std::unique_ptr<Worker>& a, const std::unique_ptr<Worker>& b)
{
    return a->getName() < b->getName();
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how should I call function sort(Workers.begin(), Workers.end(), cmp_by_name); in that case?

Comment: @DaArtagnan I am not sure what you mean.  If you chage `cmp_by_name` to the way I have it in the answer then it should work.

Answer (score 6):

The datatype of your `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Worker>>` is `std::unique_ptr<Worker>`, so your comparison function has to look like this:

```
bool cmp_by_name(const std::unique_ptr<Worker> &a, const std::unique_ptr<Worker> &b)
{
    return a->getName() < b->getName();
}
```

The comparison function expects to arguments so that an object of the `std::vector` can convert to them.

Answer (score 2):

Since [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11), you can also use a [lambda expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) instead of defining a comparison function:

```
int main()
{
    using workers_t = std::unique_ptr<Worker>;
    std::vector<workers_t> Workers;
    Workers.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Worker>(Worker("Paul")));
    Workers.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Worker>(Worker("Anna")));
    Workers.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Worker>(Worker("John")));

    std::sort(std::begin(Workers), std::end(Workers), [](const workers_t& a, const workers_t& b) {
        return a->getName() < b->getName();
    });

    for (auto const &worker : Workers)
        std::cout << worker->getName() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Note: This example directly uses `Worker` objects for the sake of clarity, but it should work for your derived `Builder` and `Driver` objects as well.

[Code on Ideone](https://ideone.com/qxwaK3)