# vector version of slow multiset

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, multiset

I want to sort my objects according to some criteria (according to how big the items are)
My funcSort in multiset slows down calculations and makes the solution does not scale. How can I make it faster?
To avoid it I tried to use vector, sort it (should go quicker?) and change it into multiset. My solution however does not work, I am not sure what I do wrong?

**Function arguments:**

```
void deliver(const std::set<MyItem::Ptr> items, MyItem::Ptr item)
```

**(Typedef of shared_ptr):**

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<MyItem> Ptr;
```

**sort function:**

```
  auto funcSort = [item](MyItem::Ptr lhs, MyItem::Ptr rhs){
        return lhs->howFar(item->howBig()) < rhs->howFar(item->howBig());
      };
```

**Original with multiset (SLOW when using funcSort):**

```
  std::multiset<MyItem::Ptr, decltype(funcSort)> sortedItems(funcSort);

  for (MyItem::Ptr item : items){
    sortedItems.insert(item);
  }
```

**My vector attempt (Error message):**

```
  std::vector<MyItem::Ptr> sortedItems;
  for (MyItem::Ptr item : items)
  {
    sortedItems.push_back(item);
  }
  std::sort(sortedItems.begin(), sortedItems.end(), funcSort());
  std::multiset<MyItem::Ptr> ms(sortedItems.begin(), sortedItems.end());
```

**Error message:**

```
   __lambda1
   auto funcSort = [item](MyItem::Ptr lhs, MyItem::Ptr rhs)
 candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: and also what "not working" means exactly.

Comment: Why do you need a multiset?  Can't you just populate the vector and sort it and now you have a sorted container?

Comment: `std::sort`, as every function, takes values, not types. You cannot pass result of `decltype` to it.

Comment: @NathanOliver if I decide to use vector I have to sort it. But sorting results in error.

Comment: @beginh Ah.  then you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380463/sorting-a-vector-of-custom-objects. or you can just get rid of the `delctype`

Comment: @NathanOliver, thank you, I was reading already this and changing my sort, but had errors in "lambda" function (updated above). I am not experienced with the c++11 notation that I want to try here out.

Comment: You have a typo.  `std::sort(sortedItems.begin(), sortedItems.end(), funcSort());` should be `std::sort(sortedItems.begin(), sortedItems.end(), funcSort);`

Comment: @NathanOliver, the problem was insert() in vector instead of push_back(). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the sort call wrong. You just want to pass the `funcSort`, not call it.

Try it like this:

```
std::sort(sortedItems.begin(), sortedItems.end(), funcSort);
```