# Best way to sort vector of characters and treat capital and lowercase letters as equal in C++?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

What I currently have is:

```
std::vector<char> test = {'a', 'f', 'b', 'g', 'c', 'K', 'E'};

int smallest;
for ( int i = 0; i < test.size() - 1; i++)
{
    smallest = i;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < test.size(); j++ )
    {
        if (test[j] < test[smallest])
            smallest = j;
    }
    int temp = test[smallest];
    test[smallest] = test[i];
    test[i] = temp;
}
```

Which sorts vector test as: {E,K,a,b,c,f,g}. However, I want to treat uppercase and lowercase letters as equals so the end result instead is: {a,b,c,E,f,g,K}. What would be best way to achieve this? I guess one way would be to reset all the values of either the capital or lowercase letters to equal each other.

Comment: essentially your question is a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380463/sorting-a-vector-of-custom-objects).  You just need to write a compare function/funtor/lambda that ignores case when comparing letters.  `tolower` or `toupper` make that easy.

Answer (score 5):

The best way would be to use `std::sort` from `<algorithm>` as such:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](char i, char j){ return std::tolower(i) < std::tolower(j); });
```

where `v` is the vector and `std::tolower` can be found in `<cctype>`. If you don't have access to C++11 lambdas, it can easily be replaced.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) with your own custom comparator, which uses [`std::tolower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) on each letter to do a case-insensitive comparison

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<char> test = {'a', 'f', 'b', 'g', 'c', 'K', 'E'};

    std::sort(begin(test),
              end(test),
              [](char lhs, char rhs)
              {
                  return std::tolower(lhs) < std::tolower(rhs);
              });

    for (auto letter: test)
    {
        std::cout << letter << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[Live demo](http://cpp.sh/9esv)

Answer (score 1):

While everyone else has suggested `std::sort` in their answer, I will suggest a solution with your algorithm, like this. (You will need [`std::tolower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) or [`std::toupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper)):

```
std::vector<char> test = {'a', 'f', 'b', 'g', 'c', 'K', 'E'};

int smallest;
for ( int i = 0; i < test.size() - 1; i++)
{
    smallest = i;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < test.size(); j++ )
    {
        if (std::tolower(test[j]) < std::tolower(test[smallest])) //Or use std::toupper
            smallest = j;
    }
    int temp = test[smallest];
    test[smallest] = test[i];
    test[i] = temp;
}
```

Comment: *While everyone else has suggested std::sort* -- And for good reason.  The algorithm the OP is using is the bubble sort, and isn't even worthy of improving on.

Comment: I just gave a direct answer, and did not want to repeat