# How to pass parameters to custom compare function for sorting in C++

Tags: c++, function, sorting, parameters, parameter-passing

I have a custom compare function:

```
bool compare(int a, int b){
    if(a>2*b) return true;
    return false;
}
```

now I want to use this function like this:

```
vector<int> numbers;//say it contains random numbers
sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), compare(a, b));//a and b are the numbers that sort function currently compares to each other
```

Obviously, this code won't work, because the program doesn't know what a and b are. My question is, how do I pass the required numbers to compare function?

Comment: You don't. `std::sort` does that.

Comment: Just `sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), compare)` works.

Comment: BTW, if that's your real function, you're in trouble - the `compare()` function needs to implement a total ordering, and this one doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good answer here on how to use std::sort

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1380496/6115571

On another note, you don't really need two return statements in your function there

```
bool compare(int a, int b) {
  return (a>2*b);
}
```

Comment: You also don't need the parentheses around the expression that's being returned. `return a>2*b;` does exactly the same thing. Some people like the parentheses, but that's strictly a matter of style.