# std::pair with a comparable and a non-comparable object needs to be sorted

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, compiler-errors

I've come across with the following problem. I have a `std::vector< std::pair<int, Move> > x` of type `std::pair<int, Move>` where `Move` is an arbitrary object not having any comparison operator defined, for example `< > !+ == <= >=` and so on.

The main reason why I paired the `Move` objects with a integer values is that the `Move` objects should have a number describing their priority for some purpose. The main intention is to sort the vector thus sorting `Move` objects using their respective integer values.

Real problem begins when I want to sort these pairs in the vector using `std::sort` function. Initially I thought that only first element of `std::pair` mattered for comparison, however, it turned out to be that both objects need comparison operations defined for them for the program to be successfully compiled.

Since I did not want to modify original `Move` class, I wrote a `Wrapper` class that was supposed to wrap `std::pair<int, Move>` and have a comparison operation defined on it so that a `std::vector< Wrapper < std::pair<int, Move> > > x;` could be sorted without having to modify `Move` class. The logic here is that `vector` is provided with a class that has `<` operation defined.

I have used the below wrapper class:

```
template <typename T>
struct Wrapper{
    Wrapper(const T & pair): pair_mem(pair)
    bool operator(const T & other_pair) const{
          return this->pair_mem.first < other_pair.first;
    }
    T pair_mem;
};
```

Well, as you may have already guessed the approach above did not work and I had to go through bunch of compiler errors. At last, I tried adding `< operator` to the Move class and even after that I was not able to compile the program.

Below is the error I think is the most important.

```
: note: this candidate was rejected because mismatch in count of arguments
    struct Wraper{
           ^
: note: this candidate was rejected because mismatch in count of arguments
            Wraper(const std::pair<int, Move> & move){
```

I am using `mpiCC` as the compiler

### UPDATE

I did change `T` to `Wrapper` as one of the answers suggested, but the problem is not solved. Here is the screenshot from the compiler,

[image]

Comment: Have you considered using a `std::map`?  It lets you build a key-value relationship that is automatically sorted.

Comment: I am actually more interested in the reason why I was not able to get it compiled.

Comment: Can you show how you used wrapper to get that error then ([mcve])?  Looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380463/sorting-a-vector-of-custom-objects) might show you what you need.

Comment: `std::vector< Wrapper < std::pair<int, Move> > > x;` is the source of the compile error. `Wrapper` is a class that has comparison defined on it. And it takes `std::pair<int, Move>`

Comment: You can pass your own comparison function to `std::sort`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your wrapper class should be similar to:

```
template <typename T>
struct Wrapper{
    Wrapper(const T & pair): pair_mem(pair) {}
    bool operator <(const Wrapper& rhs) const {
        return pair_mem.first < rhs.pair_mem.first;
    }
    T pair_mem;
};
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/uGvSzn)

But using custom comparer seems better (less intrusive).

```
std::sort(x.begin(), x.end(),
          [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) {
              return lhs.first < rhs.first;
          });
```

Comment: I actually made the operator overload operation `const`but forgot to include it here. Did not help though.

Comment: @nmd_07 The comparison parameter is a `Wrapper`, not a `T`.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Seems like the real reason.

Comment: You can use something similar to Barton-Nackman trick. Using friend, you may be able to inject the comparison operator at global scope.

Comment: @nmd_07: I have just provided a [Demo link](https://ideone.com/uGvSzn).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a c++ compiler recent enough, you can use lambda:

```
std::sort(std::begin(x), std::end(x), [](auto & l, auto & r) {return l.first < r.first; });
```

Answer (score 1):

When the compiler spits out errors, **do not skip the first message**. From your image (you really should have copied the text instead of creating an image):

> error: no instance of constructor `Wraper<T>::Wraper` matches the argument list
>   `vector(size_type __n, const value_type& __value = value_type()`

With the error indicated (by the caret on the next line) as occurring at `value_type()`. The messages you did put into your question are not errors, but explanations for what the compiler tried to do to find the missing constructor. They list the `struct` that was tried for `value_type` and the constructor that was found, the one that takes a `T` parameter. This does not match because the compiler is looking for a default constructor (no parameters).

Presumably, at line 137 of `search-abid_parallel.cpp`, you declare a vector of your wrapper class using the constructor that specifies the initial size of the vector. (Also, based on the error message, pre-C++11?) This constructor needs to be able to default-construct those initial elements. The default constructor was suppressed when you defined a different constructor, hence the error.

Some options:

1. Default initialize the vector, then call `reserve()` if you want to avoid re-allocations as you build your vector.
2. Define a default constructor for your wrapper class.
3. Don't use a wrapper class. Instead, give a comparison function to `std::sort` (the third parameter when not using a C++20 execution policy).
4. Don't use a vector. A `std::multimap` will store your pairs and keep them sorted for you.