# C++ collection not sorting

Tags: c++, sorting

```
class Polygon3D
{
public:
    float GetDepth() const
    {
    return _depth;
    }
private:
    float _depth;
};

class Model
{
public:
    void Sort(void);
    {
    std::sort(_polygons.begin(), _polygons.end(), SortMethod);
    }
private:
    std::vector<Polygon3D> _polygons;
    static bool SortMethod(const Polygon3D& lhs, const Polygon3D& rhs)
    {
        return lhs.GetDepth() < rhs.GetDepth();
    }
};
```

I hope the code above is enough to explain what I'm trying to do, which is sort by depth. However, despite the polygons having differing depths, the sort doesn't seem to do anything. Tried looking at other questions but couldn't find an answer, so not sure what I'm missing.
Thanks.

Comment: Provided code is *"correct"*. Error is in code not shown.

Comment: typo: extra `;` after `void Sort(void)`.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380463/sorting-a-vector-of-custom-objects). The answers are of relevance to your problem.

Comment: That was me not editing it properly, combining the .h and .cpp to give a better understanding of code. And I shall read that now, thanks!

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Use a 'functor' (function object - an object/class that works like a function by overloading `operator()`):

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class Polygon3D
{
public:
    Polygon3D(float depth) : _depth(depth) {}

    float GetDepth() const
    {
        return _depth;
    }
private:
    float _depth;
};

class Model
{
public:
    void InsertPolygon(Polygon3D polygon)
    {
        _polygons.push_back(polygon);
    }

    void Sort()
    {
        std::sort(_polygons.begin(), _polygons.end(), Model());
    }

    bool operator() (const Polygon3D& lhs, const Polygon3D& rhs) const
    {
        return (lhs.GetDepth() < rhs.GetDepth());
    }
private:
    std::vector<Polygon3D> _polygons;
};


int main()
{
    Model model;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        model.InsertPolygon(Polygon3D(std::rand()));

    model.Sort();

    return 0;
}
```

Or you can overload `Polygon3D`'s `operator<`, so you can call `std::sort` without having to specify a custom comparison functor:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>    

class Polygon3D
{
public:
    Polygon3D(float depth) : _depth(depth) {}

    bool operator < (const Polygon3D& rhs) const
    {
        return (this->GetDepth() < rhs.GetDepth());
    }

    float GetDepth() const
    {
        return _depth;
    }

private:
    float _depth;
};

class Model
{
public:
    void InsertPolygon(Polygon3D polygon)
    {
        _polygons.push_back(polygon);
    }

    void Sort()
    {
        std::sort(_polygons.begin(), _polygons.end());
    }
private:
    std::vector<Polygon3D> _polygons;
};


int main()
{
    Model model;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        model.InsertPolygon(Polygon3D(std::rand()));

    model.Sort();

    return 0;
}
```

Btw, you will generally receive much better response from people here if you post a minimal but *verifiable* example (i.e. one that we can copy/paste & compile without having to make changes).