# How to use sort and compare both functions to sort a char array in c++?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
// define compare function to compare between char i and j
 _____________________{       // Line-1: Write proper function header

      _____________________;   // Line-2: Write correct function body

 }
int main() {
    char data[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        cin >> data[i];

    sort(data, data + 5, compare);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        cout << data[i] << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

In the above code what will be in LINE1  and LINE2 ,

> sort(data, data + 5, compare);

in this why its taking the compare function, and I checked or compare function in c++ it takes two strings as arguments but here its not passing any arguments

Comment: `compare` will be invoked from `sort` implementation with appropriate arguments.

Comment: Looks like LINE1 and LINE2 were assigned to you to complete, not us. related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380463/sorting-a-vector-of-custom-objects

Comment: That's obviously a homework / test / interview question. Please show yor own efforts first, and whhere you got stuck with this.

Comment: Check your favorite reference for "function pointers" or "passing pointers to functions".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sort function gathers it's objects from the range that you pass, i.e. the first two parameters.

For example, it could take `data[0]` and `data[1]` as two objects.

The next step would be to compare the two items.  Usually, sorting requires comparing items.

The `sort` function calls `compare` with `data[0]` and `data[1]` to determine the ordering.

In summary, the `sort` function may call the comparison function to determine the ordering of the objects within the range you specified.

Comment: I tried this, but its showing error, can't figure out why

Comment: `bool compare(char data[i], char data[i+1])`

Comment: `retun (data[i]>data[i+1]);`

Comment: `bool compare(char a, char b) { return a > b; }` or use `return a < b;`.