# the numbers appearing closest to integer x in the vector<int> v1 must be printed first

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, iterator

Below there is a tabular view of a sorted vector.

**`vector v1=  {1 , 8 ,10 ,16}`**

**`int x=9;`**

You are given a task to reorder vector `v1` by following a rule.
You will be given a integer `x`.

**The rule is:**

> **You will print all the elements of the vector, such that, the numbers appearing closest to `x` in the vector `v1` must be printed first.**

For example the reordered vector must be `8,10,16,1`.

**sample examples:**

`x=15 . . .v1={-100,1,12,15,100} . . .  output:{15,12,1,100,-100}`

`x=99 . . .v1={-100,1,12,15,100} . . .  output:{100,15,12,1,-100}`

`x=-1 . . .v1={-100,1,12,15,100} . . .  output:{1,12,15,-100,100}`

> **In case there are two numbers that are equally closer to x, in that case, print smaller element first**

for example:

`x=0 . . .v1={-100,-50,50,100} . . .  output:{**-50**,50,**-100**,100}`

I used a naive approach, but it is too slow for larger ranges.

```
while(0 < v1.size()) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= v1.back(); j++) {
        if (x - j >= 0 && find(all(v1), x - j) != v1.end()) {
            b = x - j; break;
        }
        if (x + j <= v1.back() && find(all(v1), x + j) != v1.end()) {
            b = x + j; break;
        }
    }
    cout<<b;
    auto it2 = find(all(v1), b);
    v1.erase(it2);
}
```

Please, if you can, suggest me a faster code.

My code is way too slow.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: you can sort the vector with respect to the numbers distance to `x` and then print it, see eg here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380463/sorting-a-vector-of-custom-objects

Comment: This reads like a typical puzzle from some online quiz/hacker site. If your goal is to learn C++, you will not learn anything here. In nearly all cases, like this one, the correct solution requires knowing some kind of a mathematical or a programming trick. If you don't know what the trick is, and attempt to code a brute-force approach, your program runs forever, and fails for that reason. If you're trying to learn C++, you won't learn anything from useless online quiz sites [but only from a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: i would bet that `erase` eats the cake here, but instead of fixing single instructions you need a whole different approach as suggested above

Comment: hey @idclev463035818 i think i got your approach. i think using pairs<int,int>  wil give me a good solution. the pair will have 1.an element of vector v1 and 2.the distance of the element from v1. thankyou sir for your kind attention.

Comment: sir, if you have some other faster approach then please do tell me. otherwise i am fine with the current one to use pair<int,int>

Comment: @AshutoshKhandual you do not need a pair if you use an appropriate comparator (one of the arguments to `std::sort`)

Comment: okay now i get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elaborating on what [Aconcagua](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60155329/8735401) suggested:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

struct sortClosestToFunctor {

  explicit sortClosestToFunctor(int x) : m_x{x} {}

  bool operator()(int const lhs, int const rhs) const {
    int dx = std::abs(lhs - m_x);
    int dy = std::abs(rhs - m_x);
    return (dx < dy) or (dx == dy and lhs < rhs);
  }

private:
  int m_x;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v1{1, 8, 10, 16};
    int x = 9;

    // using functor
    std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end(), sortClosestToFunctor(9));

    // using lambda
    std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end(), [x](int const lhs, int const rhs) {
        int dx = std::abs(lhs - m_x);
        int dy = std::abs(rhs - m_x);
        return (dx < dy) or (dx == dy and lhs < rhs);
    });

    // 8 10 16 1
    std::copy(v1.begin(), v1.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

Comment: This is a bad approach. The assignment does not require to create a new vector. Otherwise it would sound like create a new vector from the given one according to the requirement. What is required is to output an already sorted vector in some order. Moreover the sorting does not guarantee that if two elements have the same distance then an element with a lower index will precede the element with a higher index.

Comment: You are correct that I missed the equal distance part. Thank you! I added it. I could argue the assignment also does not require to not reorder the vector.

Comment: As I said otherwise the assignment would sound like reorder the vector such a way that its elements would satisfy the requirement. But the assignment is only to output the vector not to rebuild it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need an appropriate comparator, then you can simply use `std::sort`:

```
std::vector<int> numbers;
int referenceValue; // = ...
std::sort
(
    numbers.begin, numbers.end,
    [/* ... */](int x, int y) { /* ... */ }
);
```

You'll get the vector sorted into exactly the order you need, no need to find and remove elements from, you can just iterate over it afterwards. `std::sort` guarantees `O(n(log(n))` (since C++11), so that should be fast enough (faster you cannot get on sorting anyway...).

Question now is: how would such a comparator look like?

Well, at very first, it will need to have the reference value available, so it will capture it:

```
[referenceValue](int x, int y) { /* ... */ }
```

As it's a simple int, capturing by value is fine, more complex types you might prefer to capture by reference instead.

The comparator should implement *'less'* semantics, so it should return `true` if x goes before y. So we can have:

```
int dx = std::abs(x - referenceValue);
int dy = std::abs(y - referenceValue);
return                        dx < dy        || dx == dy && x < y;
// if x has smaller distance: ^^^^^^^
// or, in case of equality, the smaller one  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That's it, you're done...

Untested code, if you happen to find a bug, please fix it yourself ;)

Answer (score 0):

My five cents. A straightforward approach without sorting a vector.

I am sure that it is a bad idea to sort the vector if the only task is to output it in some order. Otherwise the original vector will be changed (Why?! This is not required in the assignment.) or a copy of the vector will be created.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

std::ostream & closest_output( const std::vector<int> &v, 
                               const int &value, 
                               std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
    auto it = std::lower_bound( std::begin( v ), std::end( v ), value );

    if ( it == std::begin( v ) )
    {
        for ( auto last = std::end( v ); it != last; ++it )
        {
            os << *it << ' ';
        }
    }
    else if ( it == std::end( v ) )
    {
        for ( auto first = std::begin( v ); it != first; )
        {
            os << *--it << ' '; 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        auto next = it, first = std::begin( v ), last = std::end( v );

        while ( it != first && next != last )
        {
            if ( *next - value < value - *std::prev( it ) )
            {
                os << *next++ << ' ';
            }
            else
            {
                os << *--it << ' ';
            }
        }

        while ( it != first ) os << *--it << ' ';
        while ( next != last ) os << *next++ << ' ';
    }

    return os;
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v1 = { 1 , 8 ,10 ,16 };

    int value = 9;

    closest_output( v1, value  ) << '\n';

    std::vector<int> v2 = { -100, 1, 12, 15, 100 };

    value = 15;

    closest_output( v2, value  ) << '\n';

    value = 99;

    closest_output( v2, value  ) << '\n';

    value = 1;

    closest_output( v2, value  ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
8 10 16 1 
15 12 1 100 -100 
100 15 12 1 -100 
1 12 15 100 -100
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider if `x = 9` and `vector = {1, 8, 10, 16}`,
Then upper bound of `x` in vector is `10`,

Now if you traversal toward `begin` or toward `end` of the `vector` from `upper bound` the distance will increase with respect to `x` in both direction, because vector is sorted.

Following two step will produce required output,

1. Find distance between x and left element, and between right element and x then if left distance is less then or equal to right distance then print left element otherwise print right element,
2. If left element is printed then move one element previous to left element and if right element is printed then move next element from right element.

Now let`s apply these steps,
Here `x = 9`, `vector = {1, 8, 10, 16}` and `upper bound = 10`

1. left element = 8, right element = 10

   (9 - 8) <= (10 - 9) is true, so print 8, and now left element = 1
2. left element = 1, right element = 10

   (9 - 1) <= (10 - 9) is false, so print 10, and now right element = 16
3. left element = 1, right element = 16

   (9 - 1) <= (16 - 9) is false, so print 16, and now right element = end of 
   vector
4. left element = 1, right element = end of vector

   so print 1

These steps will produce expected output : `{8, 10, 16, 1}`
Try this implementation,

```
#include <iostream>

#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using std::cout;

template <typename ForwardIterator>
void print(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last){
    for(; last != first; ++first)
        cout<< *first<< " ";
}

void printClostestFirst(const std::vector<int>& vec, const int piotValue){
    std::vector<int>::const_iterator mid = std::upper_bound(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), piotValue);

    if(vec.cend() == mid){
        print(vec.crbegin(), vec.crend());
        return;
    }
    else if(vec.begin() == mid){
        print(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend());
        return;
    }

    std::vector<int>::const_reverse_iterator left = vec.crbegin() + std::distance(mid, vec.cend());
    std::vector<int>::const_iterator right = mid;

    std::vector<int>::const_reverse_iterator leftEnd = vec.crend();
    std::vector<int>::const_iterator rightEnd = vec.cend();

    int leftDist = 0;
    int rightDist = 0;

    while(leftEnd != left && rightEnd != right){
        leftDist = piotValue - *left;
        rightDist = *right - piotValue;

        if(leftDist <= rightDist){
            cout<< *left<< " ";
            ++left;
        }
        else{
            cout<< *right<< " ";
            ++right;
        }
    }

    if(leftEnd != left)
        print(left, leftEnd);
    else
        print(right, rightEnd);
}

int main(int , char *[]){
    cout<< "x =  9 . . .vec = { 1, 8, 10, 16 }     . . .  output: { ";
    printClostestFirst({1, 8, 10, 16}, 9);
    cout<< "}\n";

    cout<< "x = 15 . . .vec = { -100,1,12,15,100 } . . .  output: { ";
    printClostestFirst({-100,1,12,15,100}, 15);
    cout<< "}\n";

    cout<< "x = 99 . . .vec = { -100,1,12,15,100 } . . .  output: { ";
    printClostestFirst({-100,1,12,15,100}, 99);
    cout<< "}\n";

    cout<< "x = -1 . . .vec = { -100,1,12,15,100 } . . .  output: { ";
    printClostestFirst({-100,1,12,15,100}, -1);
    cout<< "}\n";

    cout<< "x =  0 . . .vec = { -100,1,12,15,100 } . . .  output: { ";
    printClostestFirst({-100,-50,50,100}, 0);
    cout<< "}\n";
}
```

output:

```
x =  9 . . .vec = { 1, 8, 10, 16 }     . . .  output: { 8 10 16 1 }
x = 15 . . .vec = { -100,1,12,15,100 } . . .  output: { 15 12 1 100 -100 }
x = 99 . . .vec = { -100,1,12,15,100 } . . .  output: { 100 15 12 1 -100 }
x = -1 . . .vec = { -100,1,12,15,100 } . . .  output: { 1 12 15 -100 100 }
x =  0 . . .vec = { -100,1,12,15,100 } . . .  output: { -50 50 -100 100 }
```