# Is there any way to sort set of pair of int and pair by greater int and smaller pair in c++?

Tags: c++, sorting, set, std-pair, stdset

I have a `set<int, pair<int, int> > ms` that I want to sort it by greater `int` and smaller `pair<int, int>`. For example, if these are the data in my set:

```
<10, pair<100, 120> >
<20, pair<45, 60> > 
<20, pair<50, 10> >
```

I want it to be this after sorting operation:

```
<20, pair<45, 60> >
<20, pair<50, 10>
<10, pair<100, 120> >
```

I know I can insert in set in descending order by [std::greater](http://cplusplus.com/forum/general/205795/) but I don't know how to combine descending and ascending!

Comment: Well, I picked the wrong duplicate and retracted my vote, so I can't vote again. Here is the correct link: [Sorting a vector of custom objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380463/sorting-a-vector-of-custom-objects). You basically have to write your own comparator for this. Maybe it would also help to write a class that holds three ints to add some semantic to those values, but that's unrelated.

Comment: @churill Oh! I get your point. Thank you

Comment: What is `set<int, pair<int, int>>`? `set` has only one `Key` parameter.

Comment: @Evg No! It can have more than one

Comment: `template<class Key, class Compare, class Allocator> class set;`. With `set<int, pair<int, int>>`, `Key = int`, `Compare = pair<int, int>`. This doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Evg I don't know what you are talking about

Comment: Try to compile `set<int, pair<int, int>>` and you'll see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216995/discussion-between-parisa-mousavi-and-evg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a custom compare operator to `std::sort`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
  std::vector<std::pair<int, std::pair<int, int>>> v = {
    std::make_pair(10, std::make_pair(100, 120)),
    std::make_pair(20, std::make_pair(45, 60)), 
    std::make_pair(20, std::make_pair(50, 10)),
  };

  std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const auto &lhs, const auto &rhs) -> bool {
      if (std::get<0>(lhs) > std::get<0>(rhs))
        return true;
      else if (std::get<0>(lhs) < std::get<0>(rhs))
        return false;
      else
        return std::get<1>(lhs) < std::get<1>(rhs);
  });

  for (const auto &e : v) {
    std::cout << e.first << " " << e.second.first << " " << e.second.second;
    std::cout << "\n";
  }
}
```

https://repl.it/repls/ComfortableAfraidKernelmode