# Sorting by different data members of a class C++

Tags: c++, class, templates, non-member-functions

So, I basically learnt class and also Template functions in C++. Suppose I have a record of students in a class with their roll number, name and total marks.
I am using index sorting to sort the records. Now the sorting can be done on the basis of name, roll or total marks. How to incorporate all three using template functions?

```
class record{
  public:
  int roll;
  string name;
  int total;
};
void sort_name(int a[], record r[],int n)
{
  int temp;
  bool xchange = true;
  for(int pass=1;pass<n&&xchange==true;pass++)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<n-pass;j++)
    {
      if(r[a[j]].name>r[a[j+1]].name)
      {
        temp=a[j];
        a[j]=a[j+1];
        a[j+1] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So instead of writing the functions again and again I want to replace r[a[j]].name by r[a[j]].roll and r[a[j]].total. Is that possible?

Comment: you should take a look at how `std::sort` does it

Comment: Use `std::sort` with `std::vector`: Does this answer your question? [Sorting a vector of custom objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380463/sorting-a-vector-of-custom-objects)

Comment: `temp=a[j]; a[j]=a[j+1]; a[j+1] = temp;` -- All of that could simply be: `std::swap(a[j], a[j+1]);`

Comment: A bubble sort? You might want to learn some more efficient sorting algorithm, or simply use the one from a standard library....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a functor as comparator to the function:

```
template <typename Comparator>
void my_sort(int a[], record r[],int n, Comparator comp)
{
    /*...*/ 
    if (comp(r[a[j], r[a[j+1]]) // instead of   if(r[a[j]].name>r[a[j+1]].name)
    /*...*/ 
}
```

Then you can call it with custom predicates, eg to compare `name` member:

```
my_sort(a,r,n,[](const record& a, const record& b) { return a.name < b.name; });
```

Unless this is an exercise about writing your own sorting routine, you should use `std::sort`. Even then you can look at how `std::sort` lets you pass a custom comparator and do similar.