# C++ STL sorting

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

```
class JewelStone {
public:
    int weight, value;
    JewelStone(int weight, int value) {
        this->weight = weight;
        this->value = value;
    }
};
```

And we have a function definition

```
int getMaxValue(vector<JewelStone*> stones, int capacity) {
}
```

How we can sort in descending order of the values?

Comment: You need to define the operator < for this class, or a function object

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380463/sorting-a-vector-of-custom-objects

Comment: In this particular case can be done using lambda expressions also.

Comment: `std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](auto &a, auto &b) { return a.value > b.value; });`

Comment: error: request for member 'value' in 'b', which is of pointer type 'JewelStone*'

Comment: getting this error same for a as well

Comment: @pallavidubey you are using a vector of pointers. Modify the lambda accordingly: `std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](auto a, auto b) { return a->value > b->value; });`