# How to swap or sort objects in vector?

Tags: c++, class, object, vector

I created one simple class `Sea`. I manually make the objects (`obj1`, `obj2`, `obj3`) and passed them to the vector:

```
vector<Sea> seaVector;
seaVector.push_back(obj1);
seaVector.push_back(obj2);
seaVector.push_back(obj3);
```

Now, I need to sort them by name alphabetically, I guess that this doesn't work the same as sorting a vector of values. I can't swap objects, either.

Please help me, I have 4 hours before the deadline.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380463/sorting-a-vector-of-custom-objects

Comment: "*Please help me, I have 4 hours before the deadline*" - this is a Q&A site, not a real-time chat site. There is never a guarantee that you will get answers in such a short amount of time. And this is not the place for people to tell you how to do your homework or competition work.

Comment: *4 hours before the deadline* That's nothing, when you become a professional programmer you'll find that the deadline was 3 months ago and your team still have months of work to do.