# how to sort a vector of string and integer pairs by the second key value which is integer?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I have a vector storing the most frequent words in a file. Initially the values was stored in a map of strings and integers but then I copied the map into the vector I thought it would be easier to sort. Then I realized that the std sort() function sorts the vector by the first key (string in this case). But I want to sort it such that the most used words at the top and the least used at the bottom.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  
  fstream fs; 
  fs.open("/Users/brah79/Downloads/skola/c++/codeTest/test.txt");
  string word; 
  map <string, int> list; 
  while(fs >> word){
    if(list.find(word) != list.end()){
      list[word]++; 
    }
    else{
      list[word] = 1; 
    }
  }

  vector <pair <string, int> > vector(list.begin(), list.end()); 

  sort(vector.begin(), vector.end() greater<int>()); 
  for(int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++){
    if(vector[i].second == 1){
      cout << vector[i].first << " is repeated " << vector[i].second << " time" << endl; 
    }
    else{
      cout << vector[i].first << " is repeated " << vector[i].second << " times" << endl;
    }
  }



  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: instead of `std::greater` use a custom comparator that compares `std::pair{second,first}`

Comment: or store the elements of the pair in other order and use `std::sort` with `std::greater`

Comment: `if(list.find(word) != list.end()){ list[word]++; } else{ list[word] = 1; }` can be simplified to `list[word]++;`. If it does not exist, it will be created with value `0` and `++` makes it `1`.

Comment: different question but accepted answer does apply https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380463/sorting-a-vector-of-custom-objects

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number you mean in a third vector<int, string> instead of vector<string, int>??

Comment: no I mean instead of copying the elements from the map to the vector as they are, write a loop and swap first and second, no additional vector needed

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number then use std::sort() on the new reversed map? I thought it's not possible to sort a map that way

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number aaa okey I think I undertand what you mean. So swap the map first then copy to the vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as mentioned in a comment, this is too complicated:

```
if(list.find(word) != list.end()){
  list[word]++; 
}
else{
  list[word] = 1; 
}
```

It looks up the key `word` twice, when it has to be looked up only once, because this does the same:

```
 list[word]++;
```

`operator[]` already does add a default constructed element if none exists in the map.

Then I see no reason to store the item you want to have sorted as `first` rather than `second`:

```
 std::vector<std::pair<int,std::string> v; // dont use same name for type and variable

 for (const auto& e : list) {  // with using namespace std there is no way to distinguish this from std::list  :(
     v.emplace_back( e.second , e.first );
 }
```

Now you can use `std::sort` with `std::greater`. Alternatively, keep the pairs as they are and write a custom comparator that compares `std::pair(second,first)`.

Comment: error: no member named emplace_back in std::vector<std::pair<int,std::string>

Comment: @brah79  `emplace_back` is available since C++11. You can use `push_back` too

Comment: I would suggest using C++17 [try_emplace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/try_emplace) method for asserting that the entry is present in the map and then using the returned iterator to increment the value. `list[word]++` it's short and does the work, but it's not explicit enough to be self-explanatory in the situations where there is no matching key in the map.

Comment: @pintarj I suppose it is personal preference. I'd use `try_emplace` (or `insert`) only when I need to know if the element was present before or not. When I do not need this information I consider `operator[]` to be more clear

Comment: @pintarj imho `map::operator[]` is explicit enough about inserting an element. If one isnt aware of that one will write buggy code and be confused about other code.