# How do I sort structs in a function

Tags: c++, sorting, struct, std

I have the following code that works fine, but now i need the output sorted whenever 1, 2, or 3 is entered into the keyboard. I'm assuming I have to create a BubbleSort function but what exactly goes into the function? This is my first time posting so forgive me if I don't have correct punctuation and indentation that is standard to this site. I included my entire code because i wasn;t sure how else to go about it, any tips are more than welcome.

The following is my code:

```
// Headers
#include <iostream>     // cout, cin
#include <cstdlib>      // exit()
#include <string>       // strings
#include <fstream>      // file processing
#include <iomanip>      // stream manipulation
using namespace std;

// Global variables
const int MAX_STUDENTS = 25;    // We will not process more than 25 students even if the file contains more
const int MAX_GRADES = 5;       // Each student has exactly 5 grades
const string FILENAME = "NamesGrades.txt";  // The name of the file that you will read

// Function declarations
int loadStudentNamesGrades(struct Student[], int grades[][MAX_GRADES], string fileName, int maxStudents);
void displayAverages(struct Student[], int grades[][MAX_GRADES], int studentCount);
void displayMax(struct Student[], int grades[][MAX_GRADES], int studentCount);
void displayMin(struct Student[], int grades[][MAX_GRADES], int studentCount);
string getLetterGrade(double grade);
int getLongestNameLength(int studentCount);

struct Student
{
    string name;        //name of student
    double average;     //average grades for student
    int max;            //holds max grade for student
    int min;            //holds min grade for student
};

Student studentNum[MAX_STUDENTS];       //creates array of struct Student

int main()
{
    int studentCount = 0;                   //assigned 0 to # of students
    int grades[MAX_STUDENTS][MAX_GRADES];   //array for table of grades for students
    //string students[MAX_STUDENTS];            //array for list of students
    char choice;                            //user input is assigned here

    // Get students and grades
    studentCount = loadStudentNamesGrades(studentNum, grades, FILENAME, MAX_STUDENTS);

    //Menu for choices
    do
    {
        // present the menu
        cout << "\nTemperature Report Program" << endl << endl;
        cout << "\t1. Display Average Grades" << endl;
        cout << "\t3. Display Mininum Grades" << endl;
        cout << "\t4. Quit Program" << endl;
        cout << "\nEnter your choice (1-4): ";

        cin >> choice;

        // the choice is then executed
        switch (choice)
        {
        case '1':   // average
            displayAverages(studentNum, grades, studentCount);
            break;

        case '2':   // max
            displayMax(studentNum, grades, studentCount);
            break;

        case'3':    // min
            displayMin(studentNum, grades, studentCount);
            break;

        case'4':    // exit
            break;

        default:    // Any other choice besides the given choices
            cout << "Invalid option. Please try again." << endl << endl;
        }

        if (choice != '4')
        {
            cout << endl;
            system("PAUSE");
            system("CLS");
        }

    } while (choice != '4');


    // End of program    
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}


//uses info in file
int loadStudentNamesGrades(Student[], int grades[][MAX_GRADES], string fileName, int maxStudents)
{
    ifstream inFile;
    string  studentName,    //student first name
    lastName;           //student last name
    int numStudents = 0;

    //opens file
    inFile.open(fileName.c_str());
    if (inFile.fail())
    {
        cout << "Could not open file" << endl;
        system("PAUSE");
        exit(1);
    }

    //loop to get names of students and grade
    for (int i = 0; i < maxStudents && (inFile >> studentName >> lastName); i++, numStudents++)
    {
        studentNum[i].name = studentName + " " + lastName;
        //gets the grade
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX_GRADES; j++)
        {
            inFile >> grades[i][j];
        }
        //students[i] = studentName + " " + lastName;
    }

    //closes file
    inFile.close();

    //returns actual number of students
    return numStudents;
}

//code for average
void displayAverages(Student[], int grades[][MAX_GRADES], int studentCount)
{
    //double average;       //average grade for students
    int sum;            //total grade(cummulative/accumulator)
    int maxLength = getLongestNameLength(studentCount);

    //will set decimal place to one point
    cout << setprecision(1) << fixed << showpoint;

    //header
    cout << "\n\nGrade Averages\n";
    cout << setw(maxLength + 1) << left << "Name"
    << setw(8) << right << "Average"
    << setw(10) << "Grade" << endl;

    //code to calculate average 
    for (int i = 0; i < studentCount; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(maxLength + 1) << left << studentNum[i].name;
        sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX_GRADES; j++)
        {
            sum += grades[i][j];
        }
        studentNum[i].average = (double)sum / MAX_GRADES;
        cout << setw(8) << right << studentNum[i].average
        << setw(10) << getLetterGrade(studentNum[i].average) << endl;
    }

}

//displays max grade for each student
void displayMax(Student[], int grades[][MAX_GRADES], int studentCount)
{
    //int maxGrade;     //max grade is stored here
    int maxLength = getLongestNameLength(studentCount);

    //header
    cout << "\n\nMax Grades\n";
    cout << setw(maxLength + 1) << left << "Name"
    << setw(4) << right << "Max"
    << setw(10) << "Grade" << endl;

    //displays students and each of their max grade
    for (int i = 0; i < studentCount; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(maxLength + 1) << left << studentNum[i].name;
        studentNum[i].max = grades[i][0];
        for (int j = 1; j < MAX_GRADES; j++)
        {
            if (studentNum[i].max < grades[i][j])
            studentNum[i].max = grades[i][j];
        }
        cout << setw(4) << right << studentNum[i].max
            << setw(10) << getLetterGrade(studentNum[i].max) << endl;
    }
}

//displays min grade for each student
void displayMin(Student[], int grades[][MAX_GRADES], int studentCount)
{
    //int minGrade;     //holds min grade
    int maxLength = getLongestNameLength(studentCount);

    //header
    cout << "\n\nMin Grades\n";
    cout << setw(maxLength + 1) << left << "Name"
    << setw(4) << right << "Min"
    << setw(10) << "Grade" << endl;

    //displays students and min grade
    for (int i = 0; i < studentCount; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(maxLength + 1) << left << studentNum[i].name;
        studentNum[i].min = grades[i][0];
        for (int j = 1; j < MAX_GRADES; j++)
        {
            if (studentNum[i].min > grades[i][j])
                studentNum[i].min = grades[i][j];
        }
        cout << setw(4) << right << studentNum[i].min
        << setw(10) << getLetterGrade(studentNum[i].min) << endl;
    }
}

//guidline for what letter grade to output for each numerical grade
string getLetterGrade(double grade)     
//changed it from char to string because it wouldnt compile
{
    if (grade >= 90)
        return "A";
    else if (grade >= 80)
        return "B";
    else if (grade >= 70)
        return "C";
    else if (grade >= 60)
        return "D";
    else
        return "F";
}

//code for table to know what length to use for spacing
int getLongestNameLength(int studentCount)
{
    int maxLength = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < studentCount; i++)
    {
        if (studentNum[i].name.length() > maxLength)
        maxLength = studentNum[i].name.length();
    }

    return maxLength;
}
```

Comment: I've look around and found websites like these but im not sure how to implement the code into my code:
[link](http://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2011/11/c-program-to-sort-array-by-using-bubble.html)

Comment: Have you considered using the qsort function? https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjXycyJr8vMAhXGOBoKHYDsBeEQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cplusplus.com%2Freference%2Fcstdlib%2Fqsort%2F&usg=AFQjCNEiK4bP9QPs4MnBLN9KqMqfZe3BgA&sig2=aBrPF3M2cCOGV9uVVb9Clw

Comment: And there are several c++ examples for bubblesort: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/127295/. BUt you might be able to use qsort. I use it more often these days now.

Comment: You want `std::sort`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181246/standard-library-sort-and-user-defined-types

Comment: @Mark Do **not** use qsort.  Your struct contains `std::string` members which are non-POD, and qsort is not designed to handle these types of objects.  Use `std::sort` instead.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie fair point!

Comment: Perhaps it should have had the std tag. I missed it.

Comment: Thanks to everyone contributing,
but since Student is a struct, and studentNum is an array of Student, what's the syntax for the follwing code where s is what im supposed to replace?
 std::sort(s.begin(), s.end());

Comment: @Mark, Are you allowed to rearrange the items in the Student array when you say you need to sort them?

Comment: I should have clarified before, yes.
The sorting needs to be from max to min grade.
SO the highest average grade is at the top, and the lowest average grade is at the bottom. The highest max grade is at the top, and the lowest max grade is at the bottom, and so on. It needs to be sorted by the grade.

Comment: @Yakk bad advice. Apologies. My comments given in good faith.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, use `std::sort`.  In addition, you could also use `std::max_element` to find the maximum (and `std::min_element` to find the minimum).

Here is `displayMax` using `std::sort`, and `std::max_element`

```
void displayMax(Student* students, int grades[][MAX_GRADES], int studentCount)
{
    //get max grade for each student
    for (int i = 0; i < studentCount; i++)
        students[i].max = *std::max_element(&grades[i][0], &grades[i][MAX_GRADES); 

    // sort students based on max
    std::sort(students, students + studentCount, [](const Student& s1, const Student& s2)
    { return s1.max > s2.max;});

    // output results
    cout << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < studentCount; ++i)
        cout << students[i].name << "  " << students[i].max << "\n";
}
```

The `max_element` function will return a pointer to the maximum value found in the range `grades[i][0]` to `grades[i][MAX_GRADES]`.  Note we have to give `std::max_element` pointers to the beginning and end items, since `max_element` and most of the other STL algorithm functions use iterators as parameters, and a pointer is an iterator type.

Then we sort the students using `std::sort`, and give the predicate that we want to sort on the max value that we set in the loop above.  Note that the sorting is done in descending order, and that is controlled by the predicate

`return s1.max > s2.max;`

In other words, return `true` if s1's maximum value is higher than s2's maximum value (meaning the items are in order), else return `false` (the items are out of order).

You would write a similar function for finding the minimum value using `std::min_element`.  To find the average, you can use `std::accumulate`, but you have a loop already set to get the average, so I guess that will work fine also (with the change to the predicate to sort on average).

[Live Demo Here](http://ideone.com/52aayU)

Answer (score 0):

use `std::sort` with a custom predicate:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Student
{
    std::string name;        //name of student
    double average;     //average grades for student
    int max;            //holds max grade for student
    int min;            //holds min grade for student
};


void sort_by_name(std::vector<Student>& v)
{
  auto by_name = [](const Student& l, const Student& r)
  {
    return l.name < r.name;
  };

  std::sort(std::begin(v), std::end(v), by_name);
}

void sort_by_average(std::vector<Student>& v)
{
  auto by_average = [](const Student& l, const Student& r)
  {
    return l.average < r.average;
  };

  std::sort(std::begin(v), std::end(v), by_average);
}

// ... and so on...
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but maybe i didnt implement it into my code correctly but the output is the same.