# C++: How to sort a vector of objects derived from class using one of its parameters

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to sort a vector of objects, created from a class in the project.

I have two classes - Playlist and ListIndex, that inherits from a List_base class. In the List_base class, I want to sort a vector of objects (either Playlist or ListIndex) by their name. the name property is defined in the List_base class. I tried using struct or function that compares the name field and pass it to the sort function. I'm getting all kinds of errors. I'm new to C++ and stuck in this error for a very long time

The List_base sort method with the compare function

```
//the function should be able to get either Playlist vector
// or ListIndex vector (both inherits from List_base)
void List_base::sortList(vector<List_base> data) {
    sort(data.begin(), data.end(), compFunc());
}

bool List_base::compFunc(List_base *a, List_base *b) {
    return a->getName().compare(b->getName()) > 0;
}
```

The name field is declared in the List_base class:

```
class List_base
{
    public:
        List_base(string name);
        string getName();
        void sortList(vector<List_base> data);
        virtual ~List_base();

    protected:

    private:
        string name;
        bool compFunc(List_base *a, List_base *b);
};
```

What am I doing wrong? I can't even focus on a specific error.
I've also tried casting but failed there too

pls, help!

Comment: "I'm getting all kinds of errors" you should post the errors and create a [MCVE]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Standard library sort and user defined types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181246/standard-library-sort-and-user-defined-types)

Answer (score 1):

`std::sort` expects the comparator you pass to be some callable type, whether that's a function pointer, functor, lambda, etc. It just needs something that can be called with a signature like `bool compare(const T& left, const T& right)`.

The first problem is that passing `compFunc()` is *calling the function* `compFunc`. This should fail because `compFunc` expects two arguments. You should pass the function itself, not its return value:

```
sort(data.begin(), data.end(), compFunc);
```

The second problem is that in your compare function you should accept the arguments by reference-to-const, not by pointer:

```
bool compFunc(const List_base& a, const List_base& b);
```

where `List_base` is exactly the element type you're sorting.

The third problem is that `compFunc` is a *non-static member function*. This means that this function depends on a `List_base` *instance* to be used, and you need a secret `this` parameter to call it, as in `this->compFunc(...)`. You should instead make it `static` or non-member, so that it can be treated as a normal function.

```
class List_base {
    /* ... */
    static bool compFunc(const List_base& a, const List_base& b);
};

bool List_base::compFunc(const List_base& a, const List_base& b){
    return a.name < b.name;
}
```

Your sorting should work at this point. If you want to use the sorted result outside of `List_base::sortList`, you should accept `data` by *reference*, so that the changes you make can be seen by the caller. Currently, `sortList` accepts the list by value, meaning that it always receives a *copy* of what you pass it.

---

Perhaps the cleanest fix to all this would be to the "less-than" operator (`<`), which the standard library uses by default in many cases to compare user-defined types. This could like something like the following:

```
class List_base {
    /* ... */
    friend bool operator<(const List_base& a, const List_base& b){
        return a.name < b.name;
    }
};
```

with this, you don't need to explicitly specify your own comparator, and sorting is now as simple as

```
sort(data.begin(), data.end());
```

Comment: another problem is that `sortList` gets the list by copy